# An alternative to CADe SIMU

Tags: motor, software, plc, cad, contactor

CADe SIMU is a industrial circuit drawning and simulation software.

I have troubles with the icons size and some bugs, so I am looking for an alternative to CADe SIMU.

I found good softwares to draw but do not allow you simulate the circuit.

I want to simulate contactors, sensors, motors, thermal relays, PLC and so on.

The CADe SIMU runs those components, but I need and alternative to this software.

Thank you.

Comment: There are a lot of good alternatives out there, do some searching. However, I am unaware of any that will "simulate a PLC". What does that really mean? Do you write you PLC code and the simulator will run that code and turn on / off IO?

Comment: @Tyler could you say some of these good alternatives for CADe SIMU (preferably free to use)?